# Can we import and export a function from a dll

Tags: dynamic, dll, import, export

I have a dll say "A.dll" which exports a function "int foo()". I have another dll say "B.dll" which consumes A.dll and uses the function foo() and also exports some other functions. Is it possible to export the function "int foo()" (imported from A.dll) from B.dll so that it can be consumed in a third dll "C.dll".

I want to know whether it is possible or not, I dont want workarounds like making A.dll available to the third dll. Also, I am not concerned if this is a bad design or not.

Thanks very much for your patience to read this through.

Kapil.

Comment: Doesn't this work by itself, by just declaring int foo() in some header?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as A.dll exports one function, this function will be available to any application (like B.dll uses it). C.dll will also be capable to import the exported functions from A.dll. Additionally, you might take the so called "Export Forwarding" (see [URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/cc301808%28en-us%29.aspx)) mechanism which enables one to export functions from B.dll and implemented these in A.dll (like \system32\sfc.dll exports functions that are forwarded to \system32\sfc_os.dll)